# Need to find out algorithim for entity recognition

Tags: machine-learning, named-entity-recognition

I am new to named entity recognition. I have a requirement to extract some specific data from corpus.

Two corpus example:

> Hi, Rajesh Das want to buy this car. Rakesh Das will use this car.
>
> Hi, Rakesh Das is brother of Rajesh Das. Rajesh Das will buy this car.

From these above example I need to extract the buyer name. So obviously the name which is near to buy word will be buyer name. Here position of Rajesh Das is different for two corpus. I can not figure out which algorithm need to implement for extracting buyer name.

I followed the https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da post which implement SpaCy and NLTK. It only provides all name list. Can someone provides me the idea how to get buyer name.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Stanford NLP tools](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/). They have a library specifically for [NER](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html). They are all written in Java, but `nltk` provides a Python wrapper for them. You can call it with:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
```

You must have Java installed of course. As far as I understood, Stanford modules are the best publicly available NLP tools around. It's worth to give it a try. There is also an independent python module called `stanfordnlp` that contains a NER tagger.

Alternatively, you might try with **Coreference Resolution** models. They are made available from library from [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/coref.html), another free software from Stanford.

All stanford tools are very good, but surprisingly heavy files.

`spacy` also have a coreference sub-module called [NeuralCoref 4.0](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) based on LSTM models. Their developers [say](https://medium.com/huggingface/state-of-the-art-neural-coreference-resolution-for-chatbots-3302365dcf30) it's state-of-the-art. I never tried it but I'll definitely will, since it looks promising.

UPDATE:
Library `neuralcoref` is absolutely fantastic for coreference resolution tasks. It's developed by Huggingface (!) and based on SpaCy. It is a very powerful tool, quick and easy to use, and I strongly suggest to use that insteaf of Stanford's CoreNLP.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task if try to build your custom ner model it would be much better. For references you can check my kaggle notebook for custom model of ner which will give you head start in designing your own dataset & preparing dataset for modeling.

[Kaggle Notebook Link](https://www.kaggle.com/swapnilpote/flight-named-entity-recognition/notebook)

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`FindTextualAnswer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTextualAnswer.html).

```
FindTextualAnswer["Hi, Rajesh Das want to buy this car. Rakesh Das will use this car.",
 "Who wants to buy the car?",
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

> "Rajesh Das"

```
FindTextualAnswer["Hi, Rakesh Das is brother of Rajesh Das. Rajesh Das will buy this car.",
 "Who wants to buy the car?",
 TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

> "Rajesh Das"

Hope his helps.

Comment: I think wolfram is not free. Right?

Comment: @Rajeshdas  They have a [Free Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/).